# How to store large arrays of booleans in file with the most light size?

Tags: arrays, file, save, boolean, stream-compaction

My program produces large arrays filled with booleans.
I need the most compact way to save those in file.

I read here http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?339670-How-is-boolean-represented-in-memory that 8 booleans in memory may represented as single byte, so single boolean is single bit.
But how I can save those arrays of booleans same compact into a file? I know - file write functions is kind of operate with bytes, instead of bits.

Shortly - I want to be able to save arrays of booleans into file, with size 8 times less than Array.Length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are coding in c++, since the link you posted leads to a c++ forum?

You can use bitmasks and bit operations, where each boolean is located at a certain bit of your byte. Therefore, you can use one byte (uint8) to store 8 booleans. This is quite low level and I used to do this when coding in C and where storage was an big issue.

If you really want to go down that road, you best hide the operations below in some higher level read/write and set/reset functions. After you transform your booleans into bytes (you have an array of bytes now!), you can simply write them to binary files as described [here](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html).

Here's some hints on how booleans can be converted to bytes:
You create masks for each boolean you're interested in to specify at what location in the byte they are going to be written / read.

I'm using hexadecimal numbers for better readability.

For example:

```
uint8 bitFlags = 0x00; // empty mask  0000 0000

uint8 maskA = 0x01;    // first bit:  0000 0001
uint8 maskB = 0x02;    // second bit: 0000 0010
```

To set a variable, use bitwise OR (preserves all other bits but sets the bit you're interested in:

```
bitFlags = bitFlags | maskA;
```

Read a variable:

```
bool isTrueA = ( bitFlags & maskA ) > 0 ; // bitwise AND, result is 1 if bit is set, 
                                          // 0 otherwise
```

Reset a variable:

```
bitFlags = bitFlags & (!maskA);           // bitwise AND with inverse mask: 1111 1110
                                          // forces position of A to be zero
```

More information on the use of bitmasks can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

Comment: You're welcome! I hope this is what you were looking for. By the way, I think it would be helpful to add c++ to the tags to make clear what language you are using.. and to better reach your audience :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this question was about any language. I were need just basic idea. But really thank you for c++ examples, instead of pascal or basic :)